# ES6 property decorator @Prop() decorator not working

Tags: babeljs, decorator

I have the following Vue typescript component class:

```
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import ChildComp from './ChildComp';

console.log(Prop);

@Component({
  template: `
        <div>
            <ChildComp></ChildComp>
        </div>
    `,
  props: {
    state: String,
  },
  components: {
    ChildComp: ChildComp,
  },
})
export default class MissionComp extends Vue {
  @Prop() test: string;

  mounted() {
    console.log(this.state, this.test);
  }
}
```

I declare 2 props, `state` through the @Component decorator (vue-class-component) and `test` through the @Prop decorator (vue-property-decorator). Only `state` works. The @Prop decorator does not add a prop to Vue, but no error is ever thrown.

The `console.log(Prop);` logs the Prop function, so the package is loaded and found, but it seems it is never executed. The application never stops at a breakpoint placed there.

I use Webpack and babel-loader for transpiling. Could the error be somwhere in the build process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem is provided by Babel. The Babel plugin [@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-plugin-proposal-decorators) currently transpiles decorators for classes and functions. To transpile class property decorators you have to use another plugin: [transform-decorators-legacy](https://github.com/loganfsmyth/babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy).